# How to access the string array elements for search?

Tags: c#

I have a text file that include of numbers and I save it in a string array.
one line of my text file is this:
2 3 9 14 23 26 34 36 39 40 52 55 59 63 67 76 85 86 90 93 99 108 114:275:5 8 1 14 10 6 10 18 12 25 7 40 1 30 18 8 2 1 5 21 10 2 21

every line save in one of indexes of string array.
now how can i access array elements as int type and search and calculate in all of array?
this is my array:

```
string [] lines = File.ReadAllLines(txtPath.Text);
```

for example I want to return indexes of array that include number'14' in all of array  .

Comment: Have you tried writing a [for loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/for)?

Comment: Stack overflow wants you to ask specific issues. You have these issues, Parsing a file, reading into an array[s], processing the array[s]. Which issue are you having exactly? Post only one issue at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the easiest and clearest way to solve it. I commented so you can better understand what happens in the entire program.

```
class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      // this is your array of strings (lines)
      string[] lines = new string[1] {
        "2 3 9 14 23 26 34 36 39 40 52 55 59 63 67 76 85 86 90 93 99 108 114:275:5 8 1 14 10 6 10 18 12 25 7 40 1 30 18 8 2 1 5 21 10 2 21"
      };

      // this dictionary contains the line index and the list of indexes containing number 14
      // in that line
      Dictionary<int, List<int>> dict = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();

      // iterating over lines array
      for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
      {
        // creating the list of indexes and the dictionary key
        List<int> indexes = new List<int>();
        dict.Add(i, indexes);
        // splitting the line by space to get numbers
        string[] lineElements = lines[i].Split(' ');
        // iterating over line elements
        for (int j = 0; j < lineElements.Length; j++)
        {
          int integerNumber;
          // checking if the string lineElements[j] is a number (because there also this case 114:275:5)
          if (int.TryParse(lineElements[j], out integerNumber))
          {
            // if it is we check if the number is 14, in that case we add that index to the indexes list
            if (integerNumber == 14)
            {
              indexes.Add(j);
            }
          }
        }
      }

      // Printing out lines and indexes:
      foreach (int key in dict.Keys)
      {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("LINE KEY: {0}", key));
        foreach (int index in dict[key])
        {
          Console.WriteLine(string.Format("INDEX ELEMENT: {0}", index));
        }
        Console.WriteLine("------------------");
      }

      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
```

**UPDATE 1:**

As you requested:

> *special thanks for your clear answering.if i want to do search for all of my array elements what can i do? it means instead of only
>   number'14' i want to print indexes of all numbers that appear in
>   indexes*

If you want to print all the indexes you should `Console.WriteLine(j)`, that is the index of the inner `for` cycle, instead of checking the number value `if (integerNumber == 14)`.

So, this is the program:

```
class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      // this is your array of strings (lines)
      string[] lines = new string[1] {
        "2 3 9 14 23 26 34 36 39 40 52 55 59 63 67 76 85 86 90 93 99 108 114:275:5 8 1 14 10 6 10 18 12 25 7 40 1 30 18 8 2 1 5 21 10 2 21"
      };

      // this dictionary contains the line index and the list of indexes containing number 14
      // in that line
      Dictionary<int, List<int>> dict = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();

      // iterating over lines array
      for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
      {
        // creating the list of indexes and the dictionary key
        List<int> indexes = new List<int>();
        dict.Add(i, indexes);
        // splitting the line by space to get numbers
        string[] lineElements = lines[i].Split(' ');
        // iterating over line elements
        for (int j = 0; j < lineElements.Length; j++)
        {
          // printing all indexes of the current line
          Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Element index: {0}", j));
        }
      }

      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
```

**UPDATE 2:**

As you requested:

> *if i want to search my line till first " : " apper and then search next line, what can i do?*

You need to break the `for` cycle when you are on the element with `:`

```
class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      // this is your array of strings (lines)
      string[] lines = new string[1] {
        "2 3 9 14 23 26 34 36 39 40 52 55 59 63 67 76 85 86 90 93 99 108 114:275:5 8 1 14 10 6 10 18 12 25 7 40 1 30 18 8 2 1 5 21 10 2 21"
      };

      // this dictionary contains the line index and the list of indexes containing number 14
      // in that line
      Dictionary<int, List<int>> dict = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();

      // iterating over lines array
      for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
      {
        // creating the list of indexes and the dictionary key
        List<int> indexes = new List<int>();
        dict.Add(i, indexes);
        // splitting the line by space to get numbers
        string[] lineElements = lines[i].Split(' ');
        // iterating over line elements
        for (int j = 0; j < lineElements.Length; j++)
        {
          // I'm saving the content of lineElements[j] as a string
          string element = lineElements[j];
          // I'm checking if the element saved as string contains the string ":"
          if (element.Contains(":"))
          {
            // If it does, I'm breaking the cycle, and I'll continue with the next line
            break;
          }
          int integerNumber;
          // checking if the string lineElements[j] is a number (because there also this case 114:275:5)
          if (int.TryParse(lineElements[j], out integerNumber))
          {
            // if it is we check if the number is 14, in that case we add that index to the indexes list
            if (integerNumber == 14)
            {
              indexes.Add(j);
            }
          }
        }
      }

      // Printing out lines and indexes:
      foreach (int key in dict.Keys)
      {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("LINE KEY: {0}", key));
        foreach (int index in dict[key])
        {
          Console.WriteLine(string.Format("INDEX ELEMENT: {0}", index));
        }
        Console.WriteLine("------------------");
      }

      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
```

As you can see, if you run this piece of code and compare it with the first version, in output you'll get only the index of the first `14` occurrence, because the second one is after the string with `:`.

Comment: special thanks for your clear answering.if i want to do search for all of my array elements what can i do? it means instead of only number'14' i want to print indexes of all numbers that appear in indexes

Comment: if i want to search my line till first " : "  apper and then search next line ,what can i do?

Answer (score 0):

First you must get all conttent of file in the string array format:

```
public string[] readAllInFile(string filepath){
            var lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
            var fileContent = string.Join(' ',lines);//join all lines of file content in one variable
            return fileContent.Split(' ');//each word(in your case each number) in one index of array
        }
```

and in usage time you can do like this:

```
var MyFileContent = readAllInFile(txtPath.Text);
int x= Convert.ToInt32(MyFileContent[2]);
IEnumerable<int> numbers = MyFileContent.Select(m=> int.Parse(m);)
var sumeOf = numbers.sum();
```

you can use linq to have more tools on collections.

Answer (score 0):

```
var linesAsInts = lines.Select(x => x.Split(' ').Select(int.Parse));

var filteredLines = linesAsInts.Where(x => x.Contains(14));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// define value delimiters.
var splitChars = new char[] { ' ', ':' };

// read lines and parse into enumerable of enumerable of ints.
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(txtPath.Text)
    .Select(x => x.Split(splitChars)
        .Select(int.Parse));

// search in array.
var occurences = lines
    .Select((line,lineIndex) => line
        .Select((integer, integerIndex) => new { integer, integerIndex })
        .Where(x => x.integer == 10)
        .Select(x => x.integerIndex));

// calculate all of array.
var total = lines.Sum(line => line.Sum());
```